# ASP.NET MVC routing with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to create a link to an url such as **home/details/1** in a jqGrid column.

The documentation shows :
showlink {baseLinkUrl: '', showAction: 'show', addParam:'&key=2'} Note: the addParam should contain &.

For example: 
formatter: ’showlink’, formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl: ’someurl.php’, addParam: ‘&action=edit’}
This will output: http: // localhost / someurl.php?id=123&action=edit

Has anyone used the formatter to create routes instead of querystrings?

Comment: will you please post your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used jqGrid but as far as I can tell, you should not set anything for `addParam`, since that'll just append it as a QueryString. Try setting your route to the `baseLinkUrl`.

Comment: { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 80, align: 'left',     formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl: '/home/details/' }},
Results in: /home/details/show?id=2undefined
The problem is how to append the ID baseLinkUrl. And get rid of undefined

Comment: Ah, I see. The formatter must be automatically appending the ID to the QueryString. I guess you'll have to write your own formatter function. I've seen some examples of it on the documentation of jqGrid.